How to Send AWS Chatbot Notifications Only to Slack Thread Without Posting in Channel?
I am using AWS chatbot and want to group similar messages in a thread. like this:
aws sns publish --topic-arn "${AWS_SNS_TOPIC_ARN}" --message '{
        "version": "1.0",
        "source": "custom",
        "content": {
            "description": "$message",
        },
        "metadata": {
            "threadId": "some_unique_name_here"
        }
    }'

According this documentation from AWS It will send every message in both thread and in the channel. I just want to send in thread and not in the channel (to aviod making extra noises in the main channel and make it messy).
Is there any official or idea to prevent this bot to send it on channel except from develop my own bot from scratch?

You can run @aws preferences in a slack channel to set your preferences for posting in this channel. This includes choosing between

Display notification updates in threads
Display notification updates in main channel
Display notification updates in threads and main channel

